# DeviceMessageLockLostException is thrown from Azure Device Client when calling CompleteAsync method sometimes

Tags: c#, azure, asynchronous, async-await, amqp

I am trying to receive the message from Azure Device Client as below

```
public async Task<List<string>> RecieveMessage(string correlationId)
        {
            var response = new List<string>();
            InitializeDeviceClient("AMQP");
            var flag = true;
            while (flag)
            {
                Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Message receivedMessage = await deviceClient.ReceiveAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));

                if (receivedMessage == null)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(100).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    continue;
                }

                Trace.WriteLine(receivedMessage.CorrelationId.ToString());
                await this.deviceClient.CompleteAsync(receivedMessage);
                if (receivedMessage.CorrelationId != correlationId)
                {
                    continue;
                }  
               
                var content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(receivedMessage.GetBytes());
                response.Add(content);
                flag = false;
            }
            return response;
        }
```

When I filter the message based on particular 'CorrelationId' then I return the response.

Here at the step when I call '*CompleteAsync*' exception is seen intermittently when running from VSTS.

```
Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Exceptions.DeviceMessageLockLostException: Exception of type 'Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Exceptions.DeviceMessageLockLostException' was thrown.
```

Stacktrace:

```
Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Transport.AmqpIoT.AmqpIoTOutcome.ThrowIfError()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Transport.Amqp.AmqpTransportHandler.DisposeMessageAsync(String lockToken, AmqpIoTDisposeActions outcome)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Transport.ErrorDelegatingHandler.<>c__DisplayClass23_0.<<ExecuteWithErrorHandlingAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Transport.ErrorDelegatingHandler.ExecuteWithErrorHandlingAsync[T](Func`1 asyncOperation)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Transport.RetryDelegatingHandler.<>c__DisplayClass26_0.<<CompleteAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Transport.RetryDelegatingHandler.CompleteAsync(String lockToken, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.InternalClient.CompleteAsync(String lockToken)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [GH issue#117](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/issues/117) and [#111](https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/issues/111), the DeviceMessageLockLostException is part of normal operation when a C2D message's TTL expired before it was acked by the device.

I will add the recommendation here:

> When you get a DeviceMessageLockLostException, the calling application
> should just trace it, ignore it and proceed. One of two things will
> happen:
>
> DeviceClient receives the same message again on ReceiveAsync(). At
> this point, the DeviceClient can try to complete the message again.
>
> DeviceClient never receives the same message again, in which case no
> action required anyways.

Comment: How to identify same message is received again? Is some condition need to be added?

Comment: Nope, it will automatically be added back to your queue. You can test this scenario.